# How to reset ng-repeat block after reordering some of it's elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat which uses an array as it's data. Now from UI, I reorder the elements using drag and drop. I have a cancel button which should reset ng-repeat so that the ordering of elements gets back according to the order of the array. I don't know how to do that. Is there any way to achieve that from angularjs or using jquery?

Comment: If not to large, make a copy of the array into a 2nd $scope variable when initializing the controller. When reset is pressed, replace the "live" array with the copy you made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be changing the your $scope variable. By doing the following, you preserved your array order and trigger ng-repeat to rerender.

```
$scope.reset = function(){

    // $scope.data is the variable that holds the array in ng repeat
    $scope.data =  angular.copy($scope.data)

}
```

Comment: this is working like charm. You saved me a day!. I was emptying the array first and then in timeout, again assign the array but that got me a lot of UI glitches. Thanks alot

Comment: No problem. Glad that this has helped u. =)